# Ajax Post call to the Rest Web Services from browser not working due to CORS

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, cors, phonegap-plugins

[click here for error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCiax.png)

**i am trying to insert data into the database through web service from the broswer but i am getting the error(screenshot).**

```
   $("#signup").click(function () {
            var radio = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
            var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var phoneno = $("#phoneno").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var dataString = "{'Cust_Type':'" + radio + "','Contact_Name':'" + fullname + "','Contact_No':'" + phoneno + "','Email':'" + email + "','Password':'" + password + "'}";

            if ($.trim(radio).length > 0 & $.trim(fullname).length > 0 & $.trim(phoneno).length > 0 & $.trim(email).length > 0 & $.trim(password).length > 0) {
                $.post({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://test.com/testWebservices/testservices.svc/mobilesignup",
                     dataType: "json",
                    data: dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function () { $("#signup").val('Connecting...'); },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "success") {
                            alert("Thank you for Registering with us! you can login now");
                        }
                        else if (data = "exist") {
                            alert("Hey! You alreay has account! you can login with us");
                        }
                        else if (data = "failed") {
                            alert("Something Went wrong");
                        }
                    }
                });
            } return false;

        });
```

**i am using phonegap to call the service api from broswer(not working) but when i am trying to call from postman plugin then its working and the data is successfully inserted into the database.**

Comment: Are your js files hosted on a Web Server (e.g. IIS)?

Comment: nope. iam creating apk file using phonegap..

Comment: In which webserver the site, test.com is hosted ?

Comment: iis server.only the service is hosted.

Comment: try on a real device, not on the browser.

Comment: tried on real device but post method not working..trying to submit a registration form.its not working showing CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

If the Test.com site is hosted in **IIS7**

Create `Web.config` file on the root directory of your application(http://test.com) and add the following XML code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE:**

***For IIS6***

1. Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager.
2. Right click the site(test.com) you want to enable CORS for and go to
   Properties.
3. Change to the HTTP Headers tab.
4. In the Custom HTTP headers section, click Add.
5. Enter `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as the header name.
6. Enter `*` as the header value.
7. Click Ok.

Comment: i am using IIS 6.but I  Have already used this code in my web.config.

Comment: getting this error " Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://test.com/testWebservices/testService.svc/mobilesignup. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)"

Comment: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code"  for chrome

Comment: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> when i put this line in web.config i get 500 internal server error.and the website is not opening..

Comment: Please proceed with the steps for IIS6 and restart the IIS server.

Comment: i did that and restarted it. after adding  
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> this statement website is not opening..please help.

Comment: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> in web.config is for IIS7. You please remove the web.config file and follow the steps for IIS6, then restart the IIS server.

Comment: i already did it. i am getting 400 bad request..CORS preflight channel did not succeed

Comment: Okay so try add these two too in the custom headers 
`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`  `Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and 
`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`  `PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS`

Comment: which file i need to add these codes...?also can u provide correct format to add this codes..